# Round floating-point value to e.g. single precision

Tags: c, floating-point, precision

C and C++ provide floating-point data types of several widths, but they leave precision unspecified. The compiler is free to use idealized arithmetic to simplify expressions, to use double precision in computing an expression over `float` values, or to use a double-precision register to keep the value of  a `float` variable or common subexpression.

Correct me if I'm wrong <sup>is wrong, see edit</sup>, but it's even legal to hoist a `float` in memory into a double-precision register, so storing a value and then loading it back doesn't necessarily truncate bits.

What is the safest, most portable way to convert a number to a lower precision? Ideally, it should be efficient too, compiling to `cvtsd2ss` on SSE2. (So, while `volatile` may be an answer, I'd prefer something better.)

**Edit:** Summarizing some of the comments and findings…

- Wider precision for intermediate results is always fair game.
- Expression simplification is allowed in C++, and in C given `FP_CONTRACT on`.
- Using double precision for a single-precision `float` is *not* allowed (in C or C++).

However, some compilers (particularly GCC on x86-32) illegally forget some precision conversions.

**Edit 2:** Some folks are expressing doubt as to the conformance of failing to narrow intermediate results.

- C11 §5.2.4.2.2/9 (same as the C99 ref cited in the answer) is specific about "remove all extra range and precision" because it specifies how other computations may be done in wider precision. Among several conforming alternative precisions is "indeterminable," which to me means no constraint whatsoever.
- C11 §7.12.2 and §6.5/8 defines `#pragma STDC FP_CONTRACT on` which enables the compiler to use infinite precision where possible.

  > The intermediate operations in the contracted expression are evaluated as if to infinite range and precision, while the final operation is rounded to the format determined by the expression evaluation method. A contracted expression might also omit the raising of floating-point exceptions.
- C++14 likewise specifically waives the constraints of finite precision and range on intermediate results. N4567 §5/12:

  > The values of the floating operands and the results of floating expressions may be represented in greater precision and range than that required by the type; the types are not changed thereby.

Note that allowing the identity `x - x = 0` to simplify `a + b - b + c` into `a + c` is not the same as making addition commutative or associative. `a + b + c` is still not the same as `a + c + b` or `a + (b + c)`, when the CPU only provides addition with two addends and a rounded result.

Comment: *" loading it back doesn't necessarily truncate bits."* I'd be curious to know where that is said. I would assume that if there is sequence point between store and load, compiler must add extra truncation operation before load is done.

Comment: "The compiler is free to use idealized arithmetic to simplify expressions" This is not true in general. For floating-point, the compiler's freedom to simplify expressions is very limited.

Comment: @user694733 I don't know where it is said, but it's what happens in practice. For [example](https://godbolt.org/g/TJ5k0h), here GCC ignores the store/load through `sum` and just goes ahead and does the additions in 80bit precision without ever truncating. Clang does it too (though it has to be told explicitly not to use SSE)

Comment: @EOF The compiler needs to be careful not to *lose* precision, but AFAIK it's free to accidentally *gain* precision. For example, `a + b - b + c` [may be simplified](https://godbolt.org/g/8lBKTm) to `a + c`.

Comment: Found this in N1570 5.2.4.2.2 p9: *"Except for **assignment and cast (which remove all extra range and precision)**, the values
yielded by operators with floating operands and values subject to the usual arithmetic
conversions and of floating constants are evaluated to a format whose range and precision
may be greater than required by the type."* I don't think it's enough to investigate single compiled and optimized function in isolation from calling code.

Comment: @user694733 Thanks, that's what I'm looking for. In C++ it's [expr] §5/12 and its footnote, "The cast and assignment operators must still perform their specific conversions…" (Would you mind posting an answer?)

Comment: Clang and GCC are broken then. That ICC is broken is already well known.

Comment: @harold To whom are you replying? Do you have a citation?

Comment: Well you already know this otherwise why ask this question, right? But for example if you compile [this](http://pastebin.com/2nL3VFjr) with `-O2 -m32 -mno-sse` with Clang or GCC, and then fill in as input say `3.4E38 3.4E38 3.4E38`, it goes ahead and prints `1.02E39` which is of course impossible since that value was assigned into a `float`.

Comment: @harold I have foggy memories of this kind of thing. (Older standards were more lenient?) I can reproduce that on GCC 5.1 but not Xcode's Clang.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: No, `a + b - b` may *not* be optimized to `a`, precisely because floating-point addition is not associative. See C11 draft standard n1570: *5.1.2.3 Program execution 14
EXAMPLE 5 Rearrangement for floating-point expressions is often restricted because of limitations in
precision as well as range. The implementation cannot generally apply the mathematical associative rules
for addition or multiplication, nor the distributive rule, because of roundoff error, even in the absence of
overflow and underflow[...]* The adjacent paragraphs are also relevant.

Comment: GCC defaults to `-fexcess-precision=fast` unless `-std=c99` (or later) is specified; and `-ffast-math` and/or `-funsafe-math-optimizations` auto-set `-fexcess-precision=fast`. Does not follow the C standard. One needs to either tell GCC to follow the standard (say, `-std=c99`), or use `-fexcess-precision=standard` and ensure neither `-ffast-math` nor `-funsafe-math-optimizations` are used.

Comment: @EOF See the previously cited paragraph in C11: "Except for assignment and cast (which remove all extra range and precision), the values yielded by operators with floating operands and values subject to the usual arithmetic conversions and of floating constants are evaluated to a format whose range and precision may be greater than required by the type. The use of evaluation formats is characterized by the implementation-defined value of `FLT_EVAL_METHOD`: `-1` ⇒ indeterminable…" It's within this implementation latitude, and in any case (as my link shows) it happens in common practice.

Comment: … (The link is C++, as it happens. I can't seem to make godbolt.org take C language switches. C++ language does not define `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` and it's always lenient.)

Comment: @NominalAnimal It's always bad to forget the language standard flag.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Yes, `a + b - b` may be evaluated in `double` precision even if `a` and `b` are of type `float`, but **it may not be optimized to `a`**.

Comment: @EOF I don't think "indeterminate" is limited to IEEE formats. Even in a stricter evaluation mode, there's also `FP_CONTRACT` per C11 §6.5/8: "The intermediate operations in the contracted expression are evaluated as if to infinite range and precision, while the final operation is rounded to the format determined by the expression evaluation method." And C++ is mum about this; its rules are taken to be looser than C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C99 5.2.4.2.2p8 excplicitly says that

> assignment and cast [..] remove all extra range and precision

So, if you want to limit the range and precision to that of a float, just cast to `float`, or assign to a `float` variable.

You can even do stuff like `(double)((float)d)` (with extra parentheses to make sure humans read it correctly), limiting a variable `d` to `float` precision and range, then casting it back to `double`. (A standard C compiler is NOT allowed to optimize that away even if `d` is a `double`; it must limit the precision and range to that of a `float`.)

I've used this in practical implementations of e.g. [Kahan summation algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm), where it can be utilized to allow the C compiler to do very aggressive optimization, but without risk of invalidation.

Comment: In C++, it's in the footnote of [expr] §5/12. Wish I could give you another upvote for the name of that algorithm… that's what I need this for too.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not so sure I share your fear here ... I tried this glorified cast-as-a-function:

```
float to_float(double x)
{
  return (float) x;
}
```

when entered into the [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/), I get this:

```
to_float(double):
        push     rbp
        mov      rbp, rsp
        movsd    QWORD PTR [rbp-8], xmm0
        cvtsd2ss xmm0, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        pop      rbp
        ret
```

That seems to generate the requested opcode (`cvtsd2ss`) right away, and I didn't even enter any compiler options to force SSE2 or anything.

I'd say that a cast has to convert to the target type, the compiler isn't free to ignore casts as far as I know.

Can you provide some case where you think the compiler can ignore a cast, that you've seen happen? Perhaps there's undefined behavior of some kind lurking in the code, which makes the compiler take unexpected shortcuts.

Comment: In this case yes. But if you, say, `return (float)(x + y + z);` where `x, y, z` are floats, and then you compile with "use x87 for floats", there's no cast.

Comment: The generated assembly is immediately recognizable as unoptimized. I'm pretty sure the OP would like something that works with optimizations enabled.